# Como fazer o login por meio de minha aplicação na Microsoft Live?

Tags: c#, autenticação

Eu gostaria de saber como eu consigo fazer login por meio de minha aplicação, seja Web ou Desktop, na Live?

Já procurei algumas coisas, mas não obtive sucesso.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Então, como o bfavaretto sugeriu, baixei um sample da microsoft, porém, ainda desta maneira, ele tem um iFrame que chama o "live.com", e esse não é o intuito, eu gostaria de fazer isso no `Server Side` para que o meu servidor fizesse essa chamada.

Segue o código da Microsoft:

```html
<h1>Welcome to the C# Sample for the Windows Live&trade; ID Web
Authentication SDK</h1>

<p>The text of the link below indicates whether you are signed in
or not. If the link invites you to <b>Sign in</b>, you are not
signed in yet. If it says <b>Sign out</b>, you are already signed
in.</p>

<iframe 
id="WebAuthControl" 
name="WebAuthControl"
src="http://login.live.com/controls/WebAuth.htm?appid=<%=AppId%>&style=font-size%3A+10pt%3B+font-family%3A+verdana%3B+background%3A+white%3B"
width="80px"
height="20px"
marginwidth="0"
marginheight="0"
align="middle"
frameborder="0"
scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Alguma outra sugestão ?

Comment: *"Já procurei algumas coisas, mas não obtive sucesso."* O que você encontrou? Por quê não obteve sucesso?

Comment: Já viu este link? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404787.aspx

Comment: @talles, tudo que eu encontrei era que não poderia fazer login, com usuário e senha, através da minha aplicação, apenas chamando a página do Live, porém, em algum momento e lugar, eu achei algo parecido com isso e tinha login para o Lie, so que nunca consegui achar novamente.

Comment: @bfavaretto, já sim, mas não tem exemplos práticos.

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte, [aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb676641.aspx "Using Web Authentication") tem um passo a passo com explicação e *snippets*. Tentou seguir?

Comment: Então, nessa página ensina apenas o redirecionamento e customização da página de Sign-in... Nada de logon externo.

Comment: A Microsoft tem [exemplos em c# para download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7843) usando o [Windows Live ID Web Authentication SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676633.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Não é possível efetuar o login na API da Microsoft usando usuário e senha**.

Esta prática não vem sendo utilizada há anos, já que implica em sérios riscos de segurança para o usuário. Em vez disso, eles implementam Oauth como forma de autenticação.

No Oauth o usuário autentica no site, neste exemplo na página da Microsoft, e depois é redirecionado para o seu site com um código (*Authorization code*) que é usado para obtenção do `access_token`, que neste caso é usado nas chamadas da api.

Encontrei [link na documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826529.aspx) que explica o processo para aplicações desktop, lá ensina a como fazer. Vale a pena lembrar que tanto para aplicações desktop como web o processo é o mesmo; a diferença é que para desktop você usará o objeto `WebBrowser` para obtenção do *authorization code*.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o nome oficial é **Identity API**.

A Microsoft disponibiliza uma biblioteca [Javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243643.aspx), mas existem outras formas de se conectar. No final, tudo se resume a operações via **REST**.

No seu caso, começaria usando a função [WL.login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh550845.aspx).

Também pode usar C#, nesse caso você começa adicionando `using Microsoft.Live`.
A [página de introdução](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641.aspx) mostra vários exemplos com C#.

Mais informações sobre a API você encontra em http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/microsoft.live.aspx.

Comment: Marcos, obrigado pela respostas, mas na verdade, meu intuito era apenas com o C#, para que eu possa aproveitar o código para outras aplicações desktop.